# Echo more rows from mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, while-loop

I have a mysql table with the following columns user_id and company_id
There are 5 records all the userid's are 5 and all companyid's are different the company_id refers to the companies table in my sql and company_id is id
I'm trying to get all  the companies in a table in html but it's not displaying all the data, it's displaying nothing, can some one help?

This is the code:

```
               <? $find = mysql_query("SELECT `bedrijf_id` FROM `users_companies` WHERE `user_id` = ".ID."") or die(mysql_error());?>
                    <? $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `bedrijven` WHERE `id` = ".$find['bedrijf_id']."") or die(mysql_error()); ?>
                    <? while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))): ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="align-center"><? echo $i; ?></td>
                            <td> <?= $row['naam']; ?></td>
                            <td> <?= $row['adres']; ?></td>
                            <td> <?= $row['postcode']; ?></td>
                            <td> <?= $row['plaats']; ?></td>
                            <td> <?= $row['land']; ?></td>
                            <td> <?= 0,$row['telefoon']; ?></td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#" class="table-icon edit" title="Edit"></a>
                                <a href="#" class="table-icon archive" title="Archive"></a>
                                <a onclick="return confirm('Weet je zeker dat je dit bedrijf  wilt verwijderen? alle gekoppelde items worden ook verwijdert zoals facturen, klanten, enz')" href="user.php?p=bedrijven&del=<?= $row['id'];?>" class="table-icon delete" title="Delete"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <? $i += 1; ?>
                    <? endwhile; ?>
```

*edit*

Hi, i added a join query, when i put the query in mysql it works perfectly, but when i set it in php it doesn't display anything also no errors.

```
<? $sql = "SELECT bedrijven.* FROM `bedrijven` LEFT JOIN `users_companies` ON(`bedrijven`.`id` = `users_companies`.`bedrijf_id`) WHERE `users_companies`.`user_id`=".ID.")";?>
                    <? while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))): ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="align-center"><? echo $i; ?></td>
                            <td> <?= $row['naam']; ?></td>
                            <td> <?= $row['adres']; ?></td>
                            <td> <?= $row['postcode']; ?></td>
                            <td> <?= $row['plaats']; ?></td>
                            <td> <?= $row['land']; ?></td>
                            <td> <?= 0,$row['telefoon']; ?></td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#" class="table-icon edit" title="Edit"></a>
                                <a href="#" class="table-icon archive"     title="Archive"></a>
                                <a onclick="return confirm('Weet je zeker dat je dit bedrijf  wilt verwijderen? alle gekoppelde items worden ook verwijdert zoals facturen, klanten, enz')" href="user.php?p=bedrijven&del=<?= $row['id'];?>" class="table-icon delete" title="Delete"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <? $i += 1; ?
```

Comment: What is `ID` in your select query.? Also avoid use of php short tags

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Comment: ID is the user session id

Comment: @Deepu: I don't like the while: endwhile; either…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first : mysql_query will be removed in the future., use the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL Instead of mysql_query

second : did you asset variable $i before you echo it ?? and your while loop must be like this

```
              <? $i = 0 ?>
              <? while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
                <tr>
                    <td class="align-center"><? echo $i; ?></td>
                    <td> <?= $row['naam']; ?></td>
                    <td> <?= $row['adres']; ?></td>
                    <td> <?= $row['postcode']; ?></td>
                    <td> <?= $row['plaats']; ?></td>
                    <td> <?= $row['land']; ?></td>
                    <td> <?= 0,$row['telefoon']; ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" class="table-icon edit" title="Edit"></a>
                        <a href="#" class="table-icon archive" title="Archive"></a>
                        <a onclick="return confirm('Weet je zeker dat je dit bedrijf  wilt verwijderen? alle gekoppelde items worden ook verwijdert zoals facturen, klanten, enz')" href="user.php?p=bedrijven&del=<?= $row['id'];?>" class="table-icon delete" title="Delete"></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <? $i += 1; ?>
            <? } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch $find before calling the second query to able to be call for $find['bedrijf_id'].

And as Dennise89 said, doing this with one query would be more optimal.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo mysql_num_rows($result) to check the result set,
```

Comment: Get one result it has to be 5